# Should we merge [sqlprofiler] tag and [sql-server-profiler] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

It appears that both of these tags refer to the same product. Googling for the description of [sqlprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlprofiler) leads me to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) and so does Googling for the text description of [sql-server-profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-profiler). In fact, the text for each of those tags appears at different places on the same page.

Since these two tags appear to be the same thing (and in a couple of cases [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-profiler+sqlprofiler), both are used at the same time), shouldn't we merge them to be just one tag? [sqlprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlprofiler) seems to have more complete information on it as well as more questions asked, so perhaps [sqlprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlprofiler) should be the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the list of questions that had the [sqlprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlprofiler) tag but not [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) or any of its related tags. There were 49 of them. Out of the 49, 4 questions were about profiling MySQL, where I removed the tag.

I synonymized [sqlprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlprofiler) to [sql-server-profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-profiler), instead of the other way round because:

1. The name of the product is SQL Server Profiler
2. SQL Profiler was a generic name and could be confused with profiling other variants of SQL.

So, the direction of the synonym is: [sql-server-profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-profiler) (× 133) ←  [sqlprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlprofiler) (× 197). I'll wait for a couple of days and then merge the tags.